# How works the EhCache's renew (timeToLive) policy?

Tags: ehcache

When I set timeToLiveSeconds="100" mean that the EhCache engine will reset all the cache or will reset only the elements that is living for 100 seconds ?

I've read the EhCache's documentation and it tends to be the first approach, by the way, I'm not totally sure about that:

> timeToLiveSeconds This is an optional attribute.
>
> Legal values are integers between 0 and Integer.MAX_VALUE.
>
> It is the number of seconds that an Element should live since it was
>   created. Created means inserted into a cache using the Cache.put
>   method.
>
> 0 has a special meaning, which is not to check the Element for time to
>   live, i.e. it will live forever.
>
> The default value is 0.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will reset **only** the element. Checkout the source code. getExpirationTime() method belongs to Element class.

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/2.5.0/net/sf/ehcache/Element.java#Element.getExpirationTime%28%29